# Need to copy row from sheet1 to sheet2 and paste the cell values on a row in sheet2 with a matching column value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, rows

I'm working on a Google Sheets that has two sheets in it that I'm using to process data from a submitted Google Forms. `sheet1` is where the new form responses are entered and `sheet2` is an "archive" of sorts, so `sheet1` only has the most recent entries that I have not looked at yet.

`sheet1` column 8 has a 5-digit number, column 9 is either blank or will say "Rcvd", the rest of the columns hold other data that just needs to be copied, but do not hold unique values.  `sheet1` and `sheet2` have identical column headers and organization, but in `sheet2`, only column 8 is filled in.

What I'd like it to do is copy all the values in a given row from `sheet1` to `sheet2` when the value in column 9 of that row is changed to "Rcvd" (on edit).  The row's values then need to be inserted into `sheet2` in the same columns, on the row with the matching value in column 8.  The given row then needs to be deleted from `sheet1`.

Thus far, I have been able to get the row to move from `sheet1` to `sheet2` and delete itself in `sheet1`, but not paste itself in a row with a matching column value in `sheet2`, only at the last row of `sheet2`.

I've been using this script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named "sheet1"
// target sheet of move to named "sheet2"
// column with rcvd is col 9 or I

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == "Rcvd") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

To me, it looks like the `.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() +1, 1)` is what needs to be changed to get the correct row number in sheet2 based on the column 8 value, but I'm not having much success getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite a doozy, but I have the functionality you want:

```
function onEdit(event) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
var columnSearchNum = 3;
var columnSearchChar = "C";
var rcvdColumn = 2;
var sourceSheetName = "Sheet1";
var targetSheetName = "Sheet2";

if(s.getName() == sourceSheetName && r.getColumn() == rcvdColumn && r.getValue() == "Rcvd") {
  var sourceRow = r.getRow();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  var targetSheetNumRows = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  //console.log(targetSheetNumRows);
  var sourceSheetNumColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getActiveRange()
  var targetValue = +s.getRange(columnSeachChar+sourceRow).getValue()
  //console.log(targetValue);
  var targetSheetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1,columnSearchNum,targetSheetNumRows,1);
  //console.log(targetSheetRange.getNumRows() +" " +targetSheetRange.getNumColumns() + " " + targetSheetRange.getValues());
  var targetRow = findIndex(targetSheetRange.getValues(), targetValue);
  //console.log(targetRow);
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 1);
  s.getRange(sourceRow, 1, 1, sourceSheetNumColumns).moveTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(sourceRow);
}
}

function findIndex(array, search){
  //console.log(array);
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    //console.log("comparing " + +array[i] + " to "+ +search);
    if (+array[i] == +search){ 
      return i+1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

You'll just need to change sheet names and columns to match your specifics

Comment: Since I'm using it with Google Forms data, it didn't let me cut form data with the moveTo command.  I changed `moveTo(target)` to `copyTo(target)` and that fixed that problem.  Thanks again!